# Call to a member function setUrl() on a non-object after security patch SUPEE-8788. Please help me with this. Magestore Giftvoucher

Tags: error, extensions, code-analysis

class Magestore_Giftvoucher_Block_Product_Upload extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId($this->getId() . '_Uploader');
    $this->setTemplate('');
    $this->getConfig()->setUrl($this->getUrl('giftvoucher/index/customUpload'));
    $this->getConfig()->setParams();
    $this->getConfig()->setFileField('image');
    $this->getConfig()->setFilters(array(
        'images' => array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
            'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.png')
        )
    ));
    $this->getConfig()->setWidth(32);
}

public function getDeleteButtonHtml()
{
    $this->setChild(
        'delete_button', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id' => '{{id}}-delete',
                'class' => 'delete',
                'type' => 'button',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(''),
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.removeFile(\'{{fileId}}\')',
                'style' => 'display:none'
            ))
    );
    return $this->getChildHtml('delete_button');
}

public function getDataMaxSize()
{
    $dataSize = Mage::helper('giftvoucher')->getInterfaceConfig('upload_max_size');
    if (is_nan($dataSize) || $dataSize <= 0) {
        $dataSize = 500;
    }
    return $dataSize . 'K';
}
```

}

Comment: Since this is a paid extension, I suggest you contact the editor.

Comment: Hi the error line is this   $this->getConfig()->setUrl($this->getUrl('giftvoucher/index/customUpload')); Do you have any idea what to edit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this same error come up for me also. What I did was go over mage store site and login into your account and download the latest version of the gift card extension (currently 4.6). Update your copy of the extension on your site. I was still getting this error after updating so I edited the file upload.php file (located at: /app/code/local/Magestore/Giftvoucher/Block/product/upload.php). Change line 43 `if (version_compare($magentoVersion, '1.9.3', '>=')){` to `if(class_exists("Mage_Uploader_Block_Abstract")){` and you will not get the error anymore